# How to update field using transaction?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image: check image here]

My document contain array of objects as shown in image I'm trying to use transaction to update `product_quantity` as the user press add or minus button. How to access the `usercart` and update product_quantity field. The code that I have right now what it does is only to create new field with its value to this document

```
Future<void> updateCartQty(qty) {
    
    DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(_currentUser!.uid)
        .collection("Cart")
        .doc(_currentUser!.uid);
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .runTransaction((transaction) async {
          // Get the document
          DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(documentReference);

          if (!snapshot.exists) {
            throw Exception("product does not exist!");
          }

          transaction.update(documentReference, {'product_quantity': qty});

         
          return qty;
        })
        .then((value) => print("update cart"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update product cart: $error"));
  }
```

Comment: Hey there, could you please explain what you have tried and why it didn't work for you?

Comment: @SamuelRomero i have uploaded the code to show what i have tried,what i need is to acceess my usercart as shown in image and update field.Up to now it just add new field to the document but this is not what i want.